# CSS Bottom not affecting element

Tags: css, positioning

```
<body>

...other stuff...

<div style="width: 30px; margin-left: 500px; bottom: 0px;">
<img src="picture.png">
</div>


</body>
```

margin-left is working. Cannot figure out why the picture won't stick to the bottom..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `bottom` to be effective, you will have to also use `position` set to `relative` or `absolute`:

```
<div style="position:absolute; width: 30px; margin-left: 500px; bottom: 0">
  <img src="picture.png">
</div>
```

Use `absolute` or `relative` position depending on your layout requirements.

***Note:*** With `position` set, you can also use `left`, `right` and `top`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly position the element to be able to use the `bottom` property:

> For **absolutely positioned** boxes, this property specifies how far the bottom margin edge of the box is offset above the bottom padding edge of its containing block.
>
> For **relatively positioned** boxes, this property specifies how far the bottom edge of the box is offset above the position it would have had in the normal flow.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Xm4Wq/)** - [source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/bottom)

Answer (score 1):

The element is missing a `position` rule for the `bottom` to take effect. [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html) has a good article on CSS positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are looking for something like this.

```
<div style="width: 30px; margin-left: 500px;">
<img src="picture.png" style='display: block;'>
</div>
```

The img by default has some space below, is above text baseline. It isn't margin or padding. The most common way to change this is to set display of image to block.